# C++ no match for operator*

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I want to overload operator:

```
static Vector operator*(float s, Vector right){
    Vector result(right.getX()*s, right.getY()*s, right.getZ()*s);
    return result;
}
```

When I want to use it:

```
Vector a(0,1,5)
Vector v(4*a);
```

I got:

```
error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'int' and 'Vector')
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Please post an[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where's this `operator*` declared? Why is it `static`?

Comment: did you try Vector v(4.0*a);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to declare (within class declaration) operator* as non-static non-member and friend like:

```
friend Vector operator*(float s, Vector right);
```

and define as (outside class declaration):

```
Vector operator*(float s, Vector right){
    return Vector(right.getX()*s, right.getY()*s, right.getZ()*s);
}
```

Operator * is used as binary operator here. If you make as member, then first argument is implicitly taken as the current object (on which * applies, for example, if you use x * y, then operator * applies on x for member). However, for non-member both the arguments can be non-Vector type and can be converted to Vector if needed. 
This will even work if you make as non-member non-friend and as static (tobe defined outside class declaration)

Comment: Works, any explanation why in this way? Something I posted as question was part of example. That's why there was static.

Comment: @keid, explained about member or nonmember

Comment: It shouldn't need to be a friend, unless the constructor or access functions are private (which would be rather odd).

Comment: @MikeSeymour if you don't declare as friend, then Vector operator*(float s, Vector right); would mean that this would require three operands, first one is implicit as current object

Comment: @DebasishJana: Only if you make it a member; why would you do that? Just make it a non-member, non-friend, and it will work.

Comment: It is marked static, so what you say about the first argument doesn't apply.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here, the function should be a non-member either static or friend, so what's the harm? upvote pls!

Answer (score -1):

According to the C++ Standard (13.5 Overloaded operators)

> 6 An operator function **shall either be a non-static member function** or
>   be a non-member function

Define the function outside the class as

```
Vector operator *( float s, const Vector &right )
{
    Vector result( right.getX() * s, right.getY() * s, right.getZ() * s );
    return result;
}
```

Take into account that member functions getX(), getY() and getZ() shall be defined with qualifier const. For example

```
float getX() const;
```

Comment: What tells you that this is a member function? If that was the problem he would receive `static Vector Vector::operator*(float, Vector)' must be either a non-static member function or a non-member function`, or something along those lines, not the error he is getting.

Comment: @Sofffia I suppose that it is declared inside the class with keyword static. In any case the quote of the Standard is very useful in this case.